# Game Development Взаимодействие Актора и игрового мира

Tags: java, разработка-игр, шаблоны-проектирования

Добрый день, вопрос состоит в следующем.

Как правильно организовать взаимодействие Актора и игрового мира?

У меня есть пара реализаций, не подскажете, какая их них идеологически правильная (или если правильной нет, то подскажите правильную)?

Есть класс игрового мира в который входят  игрок и стены. Необходимо перемещать игрока и проверять столкновение со стенами.

Код буду писать на упрощенном java-подобном псевдокоде.

```
World    
{
    Player player;
    Array Doors doors;
    Command command;

    boolean IsCollision(Player player){};
}
```

Способ №1: Актор (`player`) знает об игровом мире. Перемещение - метод класса Актора

1.1. При создании Актора в игровом мире ему передается объект мира

```
Player player = new Player(this);
```

2.2. Выполняет команду Актор

```
command.execute(player)
```

2.3. Сама Команда:

это метод класса Актора

```
void Move(x,y)
{
   this.x = x 
   this.y = y
   if (world.isCollision(this)) {returnState};  
}
```

Способ работает, но получается не очень красиво. `World` создает игрока и передается игроку в качестве параметра. При движении игрок обращается к `world` и в метод `isCollision` передает себя. Получается, как мне кажется не совсем хорошо.

Способ №2. Актор не знает об игровом мире. За перемещение отвечает игровой мир.

2.1. Выполняет команду World

```
command.execute(this);
```

2.2. Сама команда

```
movePlayer(x,y){
   if (isCollision(player)) {returnState}; 
}
```

Как все таки правильно?

**Обновление**

Еще вариант: Observer

player.move - изменяет состояние, но сохраняет предыдущее

World реагирует на событие. И в случае коллизии выполняет command.undo, которая вызывает player.returnState.

Вроде неплохо, так как Player'у передается World как интерфейс Observer.

Но опять же не знаю, правильное ли это решение с точки зрения дизайна?

Comment: @Wial, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы делал так:

1. Игрок имеет намерение выполнить движение. Он *может* узнать у Мира о том, есть ли впереди препятствие, но может и не делать этого, Миру всё равно.
2. Игрок может попросить Мир переместить его на новую позицию. Будет ли перемещение выполнено, зависит от Мира (а вдруг впереди появилось препятствие?), так что просьба не обязательно выполнится. По результатам попытки передвижения Мир выдаёт feedback.
3. Игрок не имеет контроля над собственной позицией иначе чем через Мир. То есть, о своей позиции он должен справляться у Мира.

<sub>(перенёс из комментария)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от ващих целей. Чем меньше зависимостей - тем лучше.